# Populating multiple graphs in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel macro that populates a graph from .csv files, with values starting from cells `A1`, `B1` in x and y axes. Now when I add multiple .csv files with values ranging from `A3`, `B3`, it throws an error saying the cells are empty. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Can you share the code that you are using?

Comment: http://www.2shared.com/file/Y-zly51v/macro_test.html

Comment: The following folder has a macro file and two .csv files, the macro works if one of the files is deleted..

Comment: Which line is giving you the error? I got an error on a different line which was expected but I am not getting the error that you have mentioned above.

Comment: this line       Plot_y = .Range("B1",Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

Comment: Yup I get an error in that line too but I get a different message :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the lines

```
Plot_y = Range("C1", Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Plot_x = Range("D1", Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
```

to

```
Plot_y = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Plot_x = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

And try again.

Comment: I get an error called "invalid or unqualified reference" after making this change in the very same lines

Comment: sorry my mistake, I had directly typed it here. Remove the dots before `.Rows` updating my post above